# Masstransit RabbitMQ Cancel scheduled messages

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I need some advice. We have a usecase where we want to use scheduled messages. (We immediately came out on using rabbitmq with the delayed message plugin)
But at some point we would also like to remove scheduled messages (which was one way of solving the use case, scenario A gets Triggered and then before consumption Cancelled).We tried doing this, but were not able to.

I do not have that deep of knowledge about the different exchange types. But I read online we need to use a: x-delayed-message; which we did and I can successfully schedule a message (and receive it at the posted time)
We have another work around where we could still use timed messages on our broker. But my question is: Are you able to cancel a scheduled message? And how would we do this exactly? (do you guys have any good examples?)
Our trail project uses Masstransit; we tried using the build in functionality to send/cancel a message, but the message stays on the exchange (after sending) and even after 'cancelling' it is still there and goes to the queue and gets consumed.
Thanks in advance,
Tim
PS: I also tried searching through the slack and documentation, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RabbitMQ delayed exchange plug-in does not support canceling messages that were delayed via the delayed exchange.

Comment: Thanks chris for the response, do you know if there is a clean way to produce the thing I described here? - We are even looking into way other that using a broker to do so. Quartz runs in memory so thats not the ideal solution.

Comment: Quartz.NET supports a variety of persistent storage engines, it isn't only an in-memory scheduler. [The sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Quartz) uses SQL Server, for instance.